# send a http request vb6 button click event

Tags: api, vb6, iot

By clicking on a command button i want to send a http request to turn on a light (Mqtt rest api) but don't want to open any web browser on the process.

it's kind of `get` request send.

i have tried out (as i'm using vb6 to do that)
Shell "explorer [http://blynk-cloud.com/e_6ZCMSsELAVwQH_ZvblxKY3I0CmmBDL/update/D12?value=1"](http://blynk-cloud.com/e_6ZCMSsELAVwQH_ZvblxKY3I0CmmBDL/update/D12?value=1%22)

(but the urls open with browser =). i even don't want to open the browser either.

please suggest me something which fulfills my goal

Comment: Though its name doesn't make it obvious, Microsoft's [MSXML library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762709(v=vs.85)) can be used to do HTTP requests. See the above example or [this one](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/). And many more, if you search online for _"msxml httprequest vb6"_ or _"msxml httprequest vba"_.

Comment: I'd suggest the WinHttpRequest object instead.  It can also handle newer SSL/TLS versions easily.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that a browser is inherently the wrong tool to do this as a browser typically relies on an HTTP `GET` request, and `GET` shouldn't be used on non-idempotent requests...  For instance, a browser may call a GET request as often as it likes to refresh whatever it would like.  For things that **DO** something (like turning on a real-world light), your call should use `POST`, no matter what tool you end up using.

Comment: Why not just use the WinSock control - you can synthesize and send any request with that...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you wanted an example or if you got enough info from the comments above??

This is a simple example that uses your url and demoes getting the results back. You can add headers if required, but you didn't mention that - and you didn't want to use POST.

```
Public Sub SendHTTPRequest()

    Dim request As Object
    
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    request.Open "GET", "http://blynk-cloud.com/e_6ZCMSsELAVwQH_ZvblxKY3I0CmmBDL/update/D12?value=1", False    'populates object fields
    request.send
    Debug.Print request.responseText
    
    Set request = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub SendHTTPRequest()

Set Req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
  With Req
   .open "GET", "http://blynk-cloud.com/e_6ZCMSsELAVwQH_ZvblxKY3I0CmmBDL/update/D12?value=1", False
   .send
  End With
Debug.Print Req.responseText
Set Req = Nothing  
End Sub
```

I used WinHttpRequest.
Adding the reference to "Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1"

And now it works.